# ViewPager with TabLayout inside a NavHostFragment in an AppBarLayout

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-architecture-navigation

Ok, please bear with me: I'm using the android navigation component for a new app I'm building. I need the `ActionBar` and the BottomNavigationView to hide on scroll, which I've done successfully by using an `AppBarLayout` inside a `CoordinatorLayout`.

In my app's theme I'm using "windowActionBarOverlay = true", since I need the `ActionBar` to be transparent in some of my fragments. In one of my Fragments, I have a `ViewPager` with a `TabLayout`, and a solid `ActionBar`. To overcome the issue that `windowActionBarOverlay` creates, I've added some `paddingTop` to my whole fragment.

However, this creates a problem when the user scrolls, since the ActionBar gets hidden away, and there is an empty space where the padding is.

I can use two solutions, although I don't know how to implement each of them:

1. Make the `ViewPager` scroll with the `ActionBar`. How can I do that, in my situation, where the ViewPager is inside a Fragment in a `NavHostFragment`?
2. Make the ActionBar not hide itself when the user scrolls. Is there a way to disable this programatically for particular fragments?

If anyone knows how to implement one of the two solutions, please let me know.